# How to query most popular results for one hashtag using twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying to get popular results under a certain hashtag on twitter.

However when I add "result_type=popular" to my query I get an error saying :
'The query parameter [result_type] is not one of [query,start_time,end_time,since_id,until_id,max_results,next_token,pagination_token,sort_order,expansions,tweet.fields,media.fields,poll.fields,place.fields,user.fields]',
'parameters': {'result_type': ['popular']}}],

What am I doing wrong?

```
def create_twitter_url():
    max_results = 100
    mrf = "max_results={}".format(max_results)
    starttime="2022-04-13T07:20:50.52Z"
    endtime="2022-04-19T07:20:50.52Z"
    hashtag="tesla"
    
    q = "query=%23{}&start_time={}&end_time={}&result_type=popular".format(hashtag,starttime,endtime)
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?{}&{}".format(
        mrf, q
    )


    return url 

def twitter_auth_and_connect(bearer_token, url):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

 # Put in Your Bearer Token and Import Data   
url = create_twitter_url()
bearer_token = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPD%2BbAEAAAAAZuvxYgiVmKRP8Ap7w1AcK0IxVsc%3DcZ3alOMyLkvwyq5ElC0Ii91Z6UsSQYGSj7WFx2SO5nUeqPnJAY"
twitter_auth_and_connect(bearer_token, url)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for
'sort_order':'relevancy'as query param.

I am not 100% it works the exact same as 'result_type=popular'.
But indeed show tweets for my query with high retweet counts, high likes, etc when compared to the usual sort_order (which shows the most recent latest tweets) for same query.

The "result_type=popular" is just valid for Twitter API 1.1. You are using Twitter API 2.

For 1.1 you need to either have signed previously when 2 was not out or if you signed up recently, you can ask for "Elevated Access" (Apply for additional access within the developer portal) to access standard v1.1. More details: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api